# Reproducing a crown with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to *adapt* the following crown:

[image]

What I've come up with so far is this sketch:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\tikzstyle{linha} = [line width=7pt,MaterialGrey300]
\tikzstyle{linhafina} = [line width=3pt,MaterialGrey300]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.append style={text=MaterialGrey300, 
font=\Huge},]
%\clip[fill=MaterialGrey800] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);
\fill[MaterialGrey800] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);
\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (20,20);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,20} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\normalsize\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,20} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\normalsize \y}; }

%%%% crown %%%%%
\draw[linhafina%,{Round Cap[]}-{Round Cap[]}
] (8.75,14) -- (11.25,14);
\draw[linha,yshift=-6] (9,14) -- (11,14);
\draw[linhafina%,{Round Cap[]}-{Round Cap[]}
,yshift= -12] (8.75,14) -- (11.25,14);

\draw[linhafina,-{Circle[length=5pt,yellow!80!black]}] (10,14) -- (10,15.15);
\draw[linhafina,line width=2pt] (9.6,14) -- (10,15);
\draw[linhafina,line width=2pt] (10.4,14) -- (10,15);
\draw[linhafina,line width=1.5pt] (10,14.3) -- (10.5,15);
\draw[linhafina,line width=1.5pt] (10,14.3) -- (9.5,15);

\draw[linha,line width=1.5pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}] (10,14.1) -- (9,15);
\draw[linha,line width=1.5pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}] (10,14.1) -- (11,15);



\draw[linhafina,line width=1.5pt,-{Circle[length=3.5pt]}] (10,14.3) -- (10.5,15);
\draw[linhafina,line width=1.5pt,-{Circle[length=3.5pt]}] (10,14.3) -- (9.5,15);

\draw[linha,line width=1pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}] (10,14.1) -- (9.3,14.9);
\draw[linha,line width=1pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}] (10,14.1) -- (10.7,14.9);

\draw[linha,line width=1pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}]  (9.6,14) -- (8.75,15);
\draw[linha,line width=1pt]  (9.25,14) -- (8.75,15);
\draw[linha,line width=1pt,-{Circle[length=3pt]}] (10.4,14) -- (11.25,15);
\draw[linha,line width=1pt] (10.75,14) -- (11.25,15);
\draw[linha,line width=1.5pt] (9.6,14) -- (9,15);
 \draw[linha,line width=1.5pt] (10.4,14) -- (11,15);

 \draw[linha,line width=1pt] (10.4,14) -- (10.7,14.9); 
  \draw[linha,line width=1pt] (9.6,14) -- (9.3,14.9);

\draw[linha,line width=1pt] (10.4,14) -- (10.45,14.95);
\draw[linha,line width=1pt] (9.6,14) -- (9.3,14.9);
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I believe there is also an easier way to draw the lines using nodes, but what's bothering me at the moment is that the tip of the lines slightly bulge out of the circles (you can notice if you zoom in the image).

A cross on top, like the model image (or even a fleur de lys, would also be great), although it's not my priority right now.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try `[line cap=round]` or `[line cap=butt]`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I tried doing that; there was almost no effect.

Comment: Could you please consider getting rid of the deprecated `\tikzstyle` commands in favor of `\tikzset`s?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, sure, will do. Old habits die hard.

Comment: I guess the issue was with the arrow tips. Placing a circle where the tip ends works like a charm: `\fill[white] (9.3,14.9) circle[radius=1.5pt];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not claiming this is a perfect reproduction but would like to draw your attention to `pic`s, which arguably can help a lot when drawing things that are (more or less) repetitive.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,pics/corona/.style={code={
 \draw[line width=2.5mm,fill] 
  (-8,0) -- (-10,5)-- (-6+#1,0) -- (-5+#1,5) -- (0,0) -- (5-#1,5)-- (6-#1,0) -- (10,5) --
  (8,0) -- (9.4,4) -- (6-#1,0) -- (4.8-#1,4) -- (0,0) -- (-4.8+#1,4) -- (-6+#1,0) --
  (-9.4,4) -- cycle foreach \X in {-10,\the\numexpr-5+#1,\the\numexpr5-#1,10}
  {(\X,5) circle[radius=3mm]};}},
  pics/bar/.style={code={\draw (-0.4,0) -- (0.4,0);}}]
  \path pic{corona=0} pic[scale=0.8]{corona=2};
  \draw[line width=3mm,fill] (-5,0) -- (0,6) -- (5,0) -- (0,5) -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=7mm] (0,0) -- (0,5.5);
  \fill (-8.4,0.2) -- (8.4,0.2) |- (8,-1) |- (8.4,-2) |- (-8.4,-3) |- (-8,-2)
  |- (-8.4,-1) -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=2mm]  (0,6) -- (0,8)  pic[pos=0.2]{bar} pic[pos=0.8]{bar}
   (-1,7) -- (1,7) pic[pos=0.2,rotate=90]{bar} pic[pos=0.8,rotate=90]{bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]